# How to prevent Eclipse to use a specific view for a file

Tags: xml, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a project for a product plugin which is a "plugin project" not based on the OSGI.

I have a file inside called `plugin.xml` and everytime I want to edit it I have a strange keyboard behaviour which makes me difficult to edit the XML.

The name cannot be changed but I notice if I just change it to another name the keyboard shortcuts behave differently.

I guess Eclipse detects that `plugin.xml` to be a special file, but for this project I want to know if there is any way to prevent Eclipse to detect it as a OSGI plugin (or anything else).

Comment: All Eclipse plugins are based on OSGI so I don't understand what you mean by 'not based on OSGI'.

Comment: I am developing a plugin for a product which use [JPF](http://jpf.sourceforge.net/) and contains a file plugin.xml. This framework is not OSGI and the plugin is not an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the error `Unsupported content type in editor` I preffered just to rename the file like my-plugin.xml and to rename it after when I construct the packaging (with maven assembly) like this:

```
<files>
    <file>
        <source>${project.basedir}/my-plugin.xml</source>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <destName>plugin.xml</destName>
    </file>
</files>
```

It is more a workaround but that way I can have the proper highlighting during the edition and proper name when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the plugin.xml file and select `Open With...`. Select the XML editor you want to use for the file from the list of editors. Eclipse will remember this choice for future opens.

Comment: Yes but in that case, I received a warning saying "Unsupported content type in editor" I can say to ignore that warning but it misses the coloring of the file like an xml. It opens it like a text even XML is chosen.